# Liferay 6.1.2 account confusion on login

Tags: liferay-6

I have an issue about a liferay portal: [kazagro.kz](http://www.kazagro.kz/en/). This portal has 8 sites for 8 partner companies. Each organization has its own scopes, users. They have roles as like content manager, administrator, news manager.. and so on. In one of these organizations when some user, say some manager John logins to portal, he sees that he logged in to another account as administator whose name is Sam. or vice versa sometimes admin Sam can login as manager John, even though both of them signed in by their own accounts. Does anyone met this problem?

Comment: That might be issue with SSO you are using. Provide that detail if someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try two things:
1)Reindex user
2)both users clear web browser (cache,cookies...)

Comment: it wasn't because of cache of browser, user has this issue even if he signs in from other browser.